# asp.net dynamically add connection string in web.config

Tags: asp.net, window, wep

I have web application and windows application in same solution. I want to dynamically add connection string in web.config file. The connection string information give from windows application. How do i do this please help me.

My window app having:

```
WebForm1 wf = new WebForm1();
wf.add();
```

And my wep app having:

```
 public void add()
 {
      Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
      ConnectionStringsSection sec = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
      sec.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=GKS_004-PC;Database=hello1;User ID=123;Password=123";
      config.Save();          
  }
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/217366/dynamically-set-connection-string-in-web-config    http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Programmatically-Add-or-Update-Connection-String-in-ASPNet-WebConfig-File.aspx

Comment: Think of it this way - if it's (truly) "dynamic" then, why would it need to be persisted in a config file? More importantly, each time a config file is modified, it restarts your application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you address your problem in a way that may exist a different approach to solve your issue, however in order to do what you want you have two options. First you can read the file using the `IO` namespace and then parse it like `XML` using `LINQ` nodes and second you can use the `Configuration` class (`System.Configuration` and `System.Web.Configuration` namespaces).

```
//get the configuration file
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("..."); //path to config

//get Configuration section
ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("..."); 

config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(Key, Value);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(Key);
```

or this way, instead of using directly `Configuration` class

```
AppSettingsSection appsettings = (AppSettingsSection) config.GetSection("...");
appsettings.Settings.Add(key, Value);
```